# Regex to parse a user agent string

Tags: c#, regex, user-agent

I am a total noob to regex. I have a bunch of user agent strings that I want to parse.

> Windows Phone Search (Windows Phone OS 7.10;Acer;Allegro;7.10;8860)
>      Windows Phone Search (Windows Phone OS 7.10;HTC;7 Mozart T8698;7.10;7713)
>      Windows Phone Search (Windows Phone OS 7.10;HTC;Radar C110e;7.10;7720)

How can I use regex to just extract:

A) Windows Phone OS 7.10 Acer Allegro

B) Windows Phone OS 7.10 HTC 7 Mozart

C) Windows Phone OS 7.10 HTC Radar

I have tried to use `Split` in the following way but to no avail:

```
private static string parse(string input) 
{ 
    input = input.Remove(0, input.IndexOf('(') + 1).Replace(')', ' ').Trim(); 
    string[] temp = input.Split(';'); 
    if (temp[2].Contains('T'))
    { 
        temp[2] = temp[2].Substring(0, temp[2].IndexOf('T')).Trim(); 
    } 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    sb.Append(temp[0] + " "); 
    sb.Append(temp[1] + " "); 
    sb.Append(temp[2]); 
    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any pattern or pseudocode to made up the regex?

Comment: I would use IndexOf or Split for this.

Comment: Anything wrong with simple `String.Split`? Or you want to learn regular expressions (than your question should be worded differently)...

Comment: Yup, String.Split over ';', a trim on the first match, dropping the last 2 would get you what you want. (well, almost. You'd want to further split on whitespace in the event you get "Mozart T8698")

Comment: Oh comon. I was just on the edge of posting an answer ;)

Comment: While I 'd probably go with regex instead of `Split` here for convenience, the real question is *what do you want to happen to strings that do not exactly match these patterns*? For example, note that "Allegro" is a token by its own while "Mozart" and "Radar" both have secondary tokens that you don't want to keep. What if you have a UA string with three tokens in that position? Or four? Or none?

Comment: I agree with most of the previous comments. RegEx is great for string manipulations against a large, varied body of text. But here you have relatively small, consistent fragments of text that are already in a pretty tightly defined pattern. Go with the String manipulation methods. Your sanity is the added bonus.

Comment: Rick Liddle, your comment belongs in the community wiki. Way to nail down a definable, concise reason to choose string manipulation over regex! I'll have to crib that in the future.

Comment: @RickLiddle: I don't see the "tightly defined pattern". For example, why ends one  after "Allegro" at the semicolon whereas the other strings end at the white-space?

Comment: some code for split.`code`
private static string parse(string input)
        {
            input = input.Remove(0, input.IndexOf('(') + 1).Replace(')', ' ').Trim();

            string[] temp = input.Split(';');

            if (temp[2].Contains('T'))
            {
                temp[2] = temp[2].Substring(0, temp[2].IndexOf('T')).Trim();
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(temp[0] + " ");
            sb.Append(temp[1] + " ");
            sb.Append(temp[2]);

            return sb.ToString();
        }`code`

Comment: add code tags fail! anyways, I thought utilizing regex might be more elegant.

Comment: @MatthewKnudsen Regex is perfect for this; there is no minimum or maximum size of data. If small size was a consideration, why is regex used to validate user input? I don't know why this is offtopic and closed. If you post to another forum give us a link.

Comment: @MatthewKnudsen I have provided a Regex solution on my blog. See (http://omegacoder.com/?p=991)

Comment: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php

Comment: I almost always go with regexes because they have a consistent, scalable syntax for defining patterns. You don't have to go very far with Split and IndexOf before you want to tear your hair out. Why bother? Just learn regexes and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will capture it:

```
(?<=\().*?;.*?;.*?(?=;)
```

As code it would be:

```
string s = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\().*?;.*?;.*?(?=;)").Value
```

As breakdown of the regex:

- `(?<=\()` = a "look behind" that asserts the previous char is a literal open bracket `(`
- `.*?;` = a (non-greedy - won't skip `;`) match of everything up to the next `;`
- `(?=;)` = a "look ahead" that asserts the next char is a literal semi-colon `;`

Comment: Could you change this regex to a multi line regex that explains each section of the regex? New users may find that more helpful than a one liner that they probably don't understand.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker How's that?

Answer (score 1):

I use regular expressions because it was specifically designed to parse any type of text. Once one understands the basics of the regex patterns it becomes very useful in any text situations.

In this pattern my goal is to separate each item out into named capture groups of Version, Phone, Type, Major an Minor. Once that is done by the regex processing I can use Linq to extract out the data as shown.

```
string @pattern = @"
(?:OS\s)                     # Match but don't capture (MDC) OS, used an an anchor
(?<Version>\d\.\d+)          # Version of OS
(?:;)                        # MDC ;
(?<Phone>[^;]+)              # Get phone name up to ;
(?:;)                        # MDC ;
(?<Type>[^;]+)               # Get phone type up to ;
(?:;)                        # MDC ;
(?<Major>\d\.\d+)            # Major version
(?:;)
(?<Minor>\d+)                # Minor Version
";

string data =
@"Windows Phone Search (Windows Phone OS 7.10;Acer;Allegro;7.10;8860)
Windows Phone Search (Windows Phone OS 7.10;HTC;7 Mozart T8698;7.10;7713)
Windows Phone Search (Windows Phone OS 7.10;HTC;Radar C110e;7.10;7720)";

 // Ignore pattern white space allows us to comment the pattern, it is not a regex processing command
var phones = Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                  .OfType<Match>()
                  .Select (mt => new
                  {
                    Name = mt.Groups["Phone"].Value.ToString(),
                    Type = mt.Groups["Type"].Value.ToString(),
                    Version = string.Format( "{0}.{1}", mt.Groups["Major"].Value.ToString(),
                                                        mt.Groups["Minor"].Value.ToString())
                  }
                  );

Console.WriteLine ("Phones Supported are:");

phones.Select(ph => string.Format("{0} of type {1} version ({2})", ph.Name, ph.Type, ph.Version))
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

/* Output
Phones Supported are:
Acer of type Allegro version (7.10.8860)
HTC of type 7 Mozart T8698 version (7.10.7713)
HTC of type Radar C110e version (7.10.7720)
*/
```